# checking whether two sequences have the same values in the same order (beginning java)

Tags: java, arrays, methods, sequence

I want to add a method to a class I made that checks whether the two sequences have the same values in the same order.

Here is what I have so far:

```
public class Sequence {
    private int[] values;
    public Sequence(int size) { values = new int[size]; }
    public void set(int i, int n) { values[i] = n; }
}
public boolean equals (Sequence other)
...??
```

The first part of the class I think is correct but I'm having a lot of trouble with the method that tests if the values are in the same order. Ideas and feedback would be much appreciated :)

Comment: What trouble are you having? If you want to override `equals` , method signature is `public boolean equals(Object o)`

Comment: You'll need some value of accessing the values array of the other Sequence, maybe make it public or make an accessor method (sequence.get(0) eg, and a sequence.size(), like a List)

Comment: For one thing, your `equals` method should be in your `Sequence` class.

Comment: I think you should not override the equals method.. Your requirement is whether the 2 sequences have the same values.. They are not equal.. they have the same values.. theres a difference ... U should create a new method..

Comment: @TheLostMind it's up to the programmer to decide whether the integer array contained within the `Sequence` is the only deciding factor in whether another `Sequence` is equal.

Comment: @Catchwa : I am just saying that its logically wrong... and might lead to confusion if he wants to say check if 2 sequences are equal in the future...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to say wether 2 Sequences are equals, you can override `equals` method and `hashCode` to follow contract.

Example using Eclipse tool:

```
   public class Sequence {
    private int[] values;
    public Sequence(int size) { values = new int[size]; }
    public void set(int i, int n) { values[i] = n; }


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + Arrays.hashCode(values);
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Sequence other = (Sequence) obj;
        if (!Arrays.equals(values, other.values))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

Then in a main class you can do the following thing

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Sequence s = new Sequence(5);
    Sequence s2 = new Sequence(5);// new Sequence(4)
    s.set(0, 1);
    s2.set(0, 1);
    System.out.println(s.equals(s2));//will print true      
}
```

You have to take care that if you use my comment code (new Sequence(4)) this will return false and perhaps is not what you want! Then you will have to implement your own `equals` and not autogenerated by ide.

Comment: You've overlooked the private access to the values array (I'd suggest adding a getter method).

Comment: @Catchwa you are confused, you don't need a getter method in this case, `equals` is defined in Sequence class. Try it yourself

Comment: In the method, I got an error on the line if(!Arrays.equals...... saying "Arrays could not be resolved"

Comment: @user2958597 `import java.util.Arrays;`

Comment: okay perfect! I added the import statement and it works great :) thank you!

Comment: @user2958597 Consider accepting the answer, and take care if your teacher let you use autogenerated code as i show you.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays have a built in `.equals()` method: [.equals(int[], int[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28int%5b%5d,%20int%5b%5d%29)

Very simple, but hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks :) Its just that our instructor wants us to make it a separate method and I'm a little unsure how to do that

Comment: oh, well sorry. I thought you were just looking for a way to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean equals (Sequence other) {

        // if sizez are different, automatic false
        if (this.getValues().length != other.getValues().length)
            return false;
        else 
            int[] array1 = other.getValues();
            int[] array2 = this.getValues();
            // if any indices are not equal, return false
            for (int i = 0; i < other.getValues().length; i++){
                if (array1[i] != array2[i])
                    return false;
            }

    // it not returned false, return true
    return true;
}
```

Comment: So if the input object isn't a `Sequence` object, then your method returns true? If the object types are not equal then the objects themselves should not be equal.

Comment: got a few errors saying it doesn't recognize getValues for type Sequence (do I need an import statement to fix this?) also array1 and array 2 are undefined

Comment: You need to have a getValues() in your Sequence class. `public int[] getValues(){ return values; }`

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, you will need to make your `.equals()` method a member of your Sequence class. Otherwise, you will only have access to one Sequence object.

If you want to check if 2 arrays have the same elements in the same order, all you need to do is compare each element in turn. Is the first element of this one the same as the first element of the other, etc. When you come across a pair of elements that are different, you will be able to return `false`. Otherwise, you can return `true` when you have checked each pair of elements.

One issue you may encounter is arrays of different size. Depending on what you're trying to do, you may want to either return false immediately without checking the elements or stop when you reach the end of the shorter array. Based off your question, you probably want the former, but that depends on what problem you are trying to solve.

Your `.equals()` method will be able to access the `values` arrays of both `this` and `other` even if they aren't public. This is because `.equals()` as a function of the Sequence class is allowed to access all the members of Sequence, even in Sequence objects other than `this`.

With this information, you should be able to write your `.equals()` method.

Answer (score -2):

```
public boolean equals (Sequence other){
   int[] first = this.getValues();
   int[] second = other.getValues();
   boolean same = true;
   if(first.length != second.length){
          return false;
   }
   for(int i = 0; i < first.length; i++){
       if(first[i] != second[i]){
          return false;
       }

    }
   return same;
}
```

Note: you will have to make the values array public in the Sequence class or add a getter method to the Sequence class...a getter would be the better option

Comment: I think it's safe to assume that a getter be used as opposed to making an instance variable public.

Comment: Thanks, I have made the changes to my post...you're right...a getter would be better, but making the variable public would still compile

Comment: I got two errors on the line int[] other = other.values -- "values cannot be resolved or is not a field" and "duplicate local variable other"

Comment: Now you copied mine :)

Comment: im the downvoter, cause 1st in OP didn't say that `equals` method is in Sequence class, 2nd making a custom `equals` rather than overriding `equals(Object o)` is quite confusing and not a good practice.

Comment: @JoshEngelsma - look at the answer by nachokk. There are quite a few issues with your code. e.g. if the lengths don't match you don't return straight away, if one value doesn't match you don't return straight away, etc.

Comment: Thanks for comments I have updated my code..sorry for the errors, I was trying to answer quickly, @nachokk why is it bad to make a custom equals?

Comment: Cause you are overloading `equals` method inhereted by Object class, best use `equals(Object o)` in a way that it can be use for example for collections and classes that will use `equals(Object x)` for correct behaviour!.

Comment: I understand what you are saying with regards to overloading equals though...thanks all for your input, I have changed my code now to compare to sequences for the same input in the same order, as the OP asked

Comment: a compare method between `sequence` has no sense at all, when a sequence is greater that other one? length , values? He just want observational equality of Sequence class. That's why the proper way is overriding `equals(Object x)` and `hashCode`

Comment: My bad, you're right, I will stop arguing, its getting too late over here... I just dont like being downvoted :) Thanks for your input, So I guess mine will check for equality of the two sequences, it is just restricted to Sequence objects...is that what you are saying?